# pass pem file,certificate and user to authenticate

Tags: python, python-requests, chef-infra

I am trying to authenticate with chef api. To authenticate with chef api i need to pass in pem file, user and certificate. How can i pass that using requests module.

Below is what i am trying

```
r = requests.get('https://example.com', cert=(cert_file,ca_file), auth=('user') )
```

I went through these documents 
https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

I know pychef is available to interact with chef server , but i want to do it through requests module . Can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [pychef](https://github.com/coderanger/pychef) by [coderanger](https://github.com/coderanger) or you can get an inspiration from [chef-api](https://github.com/tas50/chef-api)